# TypeScript : Child process failed to process the request: Error: Debug Failure

Tags: javascript, typescript, nwb

I am getting below error in typescript while doing `nwb serve-react-demo`

> Child process failed to process the request: Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
> at resolveNamesWithLocalCache (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121409:26)
> at Object.resolveModuleNames (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121453:20)
> at Object.resolveModuleNames (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:123372:134)
> at actualResolveModuleNamesWorker (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:116593:153)
> at resolveModuleNamesWorker (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:116896:26)
> at resolveModuleNamesReusingOldState (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:116994:24)
> at processImportedModules (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118504:35)
> at findSourceFileWorker (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118284:17)
> at findSourceFile (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118133:26)
> at processImportedModules (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118539:25)
> at findSourceFileWorker (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118284:17)
> at findSourceFile (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118133:26)
> at processImportedModules (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118539:25)
> at findSourceFileWorker (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118284:17)
> at findSourceFile (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118133:26)
> at processImportedModules (D:\Projects\react-techpulse-components\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:118539:25)

I am using 4.7.2 version of typescript.

Below is my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7", "es2017", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts",
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "tests/**",
  ]
}
```

And below is my webpack config file

```
var config = {
  type: 'react-component',
  npm: {
    esModules: true,
    umd: false
  },
  webpack: {
    config(config) {
      config.entry = {
        demo: ['./demo/src/index.js'],
      }
      config.resolve.extensions = ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
      config.module.rules.push({
        'test': /\.tsx?$/,
        'loader': 'awesome-typescript-loader',
      },{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          {
            // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "includePaths": ['src/styles', 'node_modules']
            }
          }
        ]
    })

      return config
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `"ts-loader"` instead of `"awesome-typescript-loader"`.

Comment: how can i replace awesome-typescript-loader with ts-loader in an existing project?

Comment: replace ```'loader': 'awesome-typescript-loader'``` with ```'loader': 'ts-loader'``` and in packages.json add in  ```"devDependencies"``` sequence, line : ```"ts-loader": "^9.3.1",```
run the command :   ```yarn install``` (or ```npm instal```)  and after that ```yarn start``` (or ```npm start```)